# File size limit for uploads into aws s3 in OctoberCMS Media Library

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, octobercms, octobercms-backend

My client is having issues uploading into October CMS's Media Library a video that is more than 256 MB.

Is there a setting to lift this limit either in AWS or in October CMS config/filesystem.php or elsewhere?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your PHP configuration, edit php.ini and change the following value:

```
post_max_size = 300M 
upload_max_filesize = 300M
memory_limit = 700M
```

For more info read the following thread in October CMS website:

https://octobercms.com/forum/post/media-error-after-uploading-a-file